# Tkinker and online resizing of .jpg with Pillow (PIL)

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, python-imaging-library

Trying to include a slider to resize images online in a Tkinker-GUI-Application of python.

Problem: Canvas Resizing works, Inital Show of original sized image, too. But when using the slider the picture is not resized - it just shows very short in the adjusted size and is then somehow "overwritten" by the original one.

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import width
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import FileDownloader

window = Tk()
window.title ('Price Catcher')

#PIL to open a jpg and store a Tk compatible objekct
headerpic = Image.open("./10374_0.jpg")

def resizePictures(scalerValue):
    print(scalerValue)
    print(window.canvas.find_all())
    headerpicTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(headerpic.resize((int(scalerValue), int(scalerValue)), Image.ANTIALIAS))
    window.canvas.config(width=int(scalerValue), height=int(scalerValue))
    #window.canvas.delete("all")
    canvas_id = window.canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=headerpicTk)
    window.canvas.update()
    
#Picture Resizer
PicResizeScale = IntVar() #Control Variable to use for Picture Resizing Value of Scaler
window.scale = Scale(window, label='Bildgröße in %', orient=HORIZONTAL, resolution=10, length=300, from_=0, to=200, command=resizePictures)
window.scale.set(100)
window.scale.pack(side=TOP)

#PIL to open a jpg and store a Tk compatible objekct
headerpic = Image.open("./10374_0.jpg")
headerpicTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(headerpic)

#Place the opject to the canvas
window.canvas = Canvas(window, width=100, height=100)
window.canvas.pack()
canvas_id = window.canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=headerpicTk)

window.downloadbutton = Button(window, text='Download Bild', command=FileDownloader.FileDownloader("https://www.silbertresor.de/images/product_images/info_images/10374_0.jpg", ".\\10374_0.jpg"), justify= LEFT)
window.downloadbutton.pack(side = BOTTOM)
window.exitbutton = Button(window, text='Schließen', command=exit, justify= RIGHT)
window.exitbutton.pack(side= BOTTOM)

window.mainloop()
```

Any hints - i'm lost :(..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PhotoImage` has bug which removes image when it is assigned to local variable in function.

And inside `resizePictures` you assign new `PhotoImage` to local variable `headerpicTk`.

You have to add `global headerpicTk` to assign `PhotoImage` to global variable `headerpicTk`.

```
def resizePictures(scalerValue):
    global headerpicTk

    print(scalerValue)

    # ...rest ...
```

That's all.